TYPO3 12 Context API - user aspect get custom fe_user property
My fe_user table has different custom attributes. Now I want to access these attributes via the Context API as follows:
$context = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Context::class);
$context->getPropertyFromAspect('frontend.user', 'xxxx');

This doesn't work because of the implementation in TYPO3\CMS\Core\Context\UserAspect
public function get(string $name)
{
  switch ($name) {
    case 'id':
      return (int)($this->user
        ->user[$this->user->userid_column ?? 'uid'] ?? 0
      );
    case 'username':
      return (string)($this->user
        ->user[$this->user->username_column ?? 'username'] ?? ''
      );
    case 'isLoggedIn':
      return $this->isLoggedIn();
    case 'isAdmin':
      return $this->isAdmin();
    case 'groupIds':
      return $this->getGroupIds();
    case 'groupNames':
      return $this->getGroupNames();
  }
  throw new AspectPropertyNotFoundException(
    'Property "' . $name . '" not found in Aspect "'
      . __CLASS__ . '".',
    1529996567
  );
}

How do I access these properties other than the old way via
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['xxx']


I think there are three ways:
1.)
Grab the Id of the user:
$context = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(Context::class);
$userId = $context->getPropertyFromAspect('frontend.user', 'xxxx');

1a.)
And then use the Querybuilder to access fe_user table and fetch the data you need.
or
1b.)
Implement your own Model and Repository for the frontenduser and fetch the data via the repository.
2.)
Implement a CustomUserAspect class that extend the UserAspect class. Now you could add the CustomUserAspect to the Context and fetch the data that way.
I think i would use the old way as long as possible and then prefer solution 1a.
